# TYPO3 7.6 Form upload field same filename

Tags: html, forms, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

One of our customers is using a jobform based on the old form extension which is shipped with the core. Everything is configured in TypoScript.

In the form are two upload fields for the CV and the motivation-letter. When now two website visitors are submitting the form with identical filenames for the uploaded files the HR gets in the e-mail just the files which the first visitors has uploaded.

Is there a solution in the old ext_form extension for this exceptional behavior?

```
#reuse the wraps and modification of the modified form  
form.20 {

  stdWrap.wrap = <div class="l-grid">|</div>
  layout(

  <div class="form-element l-grid-cell l-one-half l-mobile-one-whole"><label class="form-label t-lead">###LABEL### ###FIELD###</label></div>
  )
  COMMENT (

  <div class="formRow comment">###LABEL### ###FIELD###</div>
  )
  CHECK.layout(

  <div class="form-checkbox-wrapper">###FIELD### ###LABEL###</div>
  )
  RADIO.layout(

  <div class="form-element l-grid-cell l-one-half l-mobile-one-whole">###FIELD### ###LABEL###</div>
  )  
  CAPTCHA.layout(

  <div class="formRow captchaImage">###LABEL### ###FIELD###</div>
  )
  TEXTAREA.layout(
  <div class="form-element l-grid-cell l-one-whole"><label class="form-label t-lead">###LABEL### ###FIELD###</label></div>
  )
  SELECT.layout(
  <div class="form-element l-grid-cell l-one-whole"><label class="form-label t-lead">###LABEL### ###FIELD###</label></div>
  )

  REQ.labelWrap.wrap = | *
  REQ = 1

  commentWrap.wrap = |
  radioWrap.accessibilityWrap.wrap = |

  badMess = {$sitevarsL.mailform.badMess}
  target = {$styles.content.mailform.target}

  params = class="form-text"
  params.password = class="password"
  params.textarea = class="form-textarea"
  params.file = class="file"
  params.submit = class="button button--color-pink t-button"
  params.reset = class="reset"
  params.radio = class="form-radio"
  params.check = class="form-checkbox"
  params.select = class="select"

  fieldPrefix = 0

  dataArray.9 {
    type = last_url=hidden
    value = {getenv:HTTP_REFERER}
    value.insertData = 1
  }

  formName >
  dontMd5FieldNames = 0




  dataArray {
    170 <
    180 <
    190 <
    185 <
    212 < .200
    212.required = 0
    212 {
      label.data >
      label = {$TEXT.jobs_form_telefonfac}
    }
    200 <
    205 <

    225 <

    120 {
      label.data >
      label = {$TEXT.jobs_form_first_name}
    }
    130 {
      label.data >
      label = {$TEXT.jobs_form_last_name}
    }
    210 {
      label.data >
      label = {$TEXT.jobs_form_email}
    }
    215 {
      label.data >
      label = {$TEXT.jobs_form_cv}
    }
    220 {
      label.data >
      label = {$TEXT.jobs_form_doc}

    }
    225 >
    225 {
       label= {$TEXT.jobs_form_attachments}
    }
    230 {
      label.data >
      label = {$TEXT.jobs_form_comment}
    }
    250 {
      value.data >
      value = {$TEXT.jobs_form_send}

    }
  }

}
```